# Why GameStop is a case of "predatory trading"?

Tags: trading

Predatory trading is defined as below by [Brunnermeier, 2005](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1540-6261.2005.00781.x)

> This paper studies predatory trading, trading that induces and/or
> exploits the need of other investors to reduce their positions. **We
> show that if one trader needs to sell, others also sell and
> subsequently buy back the asset. This leads to price overshooting and
> a reduced liquidation value for the distressed trader**. Hence, the
> market is illiquid when liquidity is most needed. Further, a trader
> profits from triggering another trader's crisis, and the crisis can
> spill over across traders and across markets.

[Hasso, 2021](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S154461232100221X) documented that **GameStop is an example of predatory trading**

> GameStop was the first case of predatory trading credited to retail
> investors.

I still have not fully link the GameStop case and "predatory trading" as above, could you please help me to sort it out?

Comment: Are you sure they are both using the exact same definition? And does it really matter?

Comment: +1 for the "does it really matter"

Comment: @BobJansen they are using the same definition, Hasso,2021 directly cite the paper of Brunnermeier, 2005 in his paper regarding "predatory trading"

Comment: It matters to me because I try to understand why GameStop is an example of predatory trading. Although I read the definition but I still cannot link. It encourages me to ask here to clarify my mind. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the people buying the stock while saying "i like this stonk", simultaneously stiffling a smirk, were only buying gamestop because they liked the fundamentals, wanted to support a high street store through a difficult time, or some other similar reason, then i think you can say happily that it was not predatory trading.

If however people were buying the shares because they were aware that a market particpant held significant short positions and would need to liquidate (i.e. buy back) large quantities of stock to satisfy margin calls, or cut shorts due to poor mtm (leading to the same buying pressure), then they are directly profiting from their own market impact, triggering a crisis with another trader and directly benefiting from it. This absolutely is predatory trading.

The third scenario is that people are buying the stocks because they see the news, they think they can make a quick buck, go on wall street bets, read that they should buy stock X because it will go up, and so they just buy in because FOMO. IMO this is also predatory - just because someone is oblivious of the implications of their trading activity, it does not change what it was.

It was almost certainly a combination of the three above, IMO it was absolutely predatory behaviour - we saw the same people buying sending out a large quantity of negative memes and other stuff about melvin - exactly the person they were negatively impacting with their trading - Apes make money, Melvin loses = hilarious, justice, right. Stock price goes down, triggering stop losses on massively leveraged margin trades = evil manipulation.

I think it is unliekly this conclusion will ever be reached though, there is no value in the SEC determining this - all that will happen is retail investors will either angrilly claim the market is rigged, or they won't understand what has happened and end up with the same conclusion that it's unfair and against them. I think that what is more likely is that robin hood and other brokerages will be found to have been allowing trading activity which did not maintain stable markets and fined for it.

my 2c.

tldr: IMO it was predatory, but in this instance nothing will come of it - retail investors will be left alone.

Comment: I agree.  Regulators will never accuse multiple retail traders of improper trading of this nature.  If a bank did it , that would be another story.

Comment: Thanks @ưill, I understand all until this paragraph, could you please explain more why it is the combination then ? "**It was almost certainly a combination of the three above, IMO it was absolutely predatory behaviour - we saw the same people buying sending out a large quantity of negative memes and other stuff about melvin - exactly the person they were negatively impacting with their trading - Apes make money, Melvin loses = hilarious, justice, right. Stock price goes down, triggering stop losses on massively leveraged margin trades = evil manipulation.**"